# Validate that exposed primary/foreign keys in a form are intact

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Survey form. Every question has 3-4 pre-defined answers as radio buttons. The value of a radio button is the primary key of the answer in the database.

As all answers to all questions are stored in one table, if a user increments the value, the ID may still be a valid foreign key, but it does not belong to that question.

What's the best practice to be sure the value of the radio button is not manipulated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> be sure the value of radiobutton is not manipulated

You can't, and that's the wrong approach.  *Always* assume that client-side information *can* be manipulated.

Instead, validate the business logic of the request being made to the server.  When your server-side code receives a submitted set of questions and answers, verify against the data you have that the data being submitted is valid.

This could be done by querying your database first, performing your validation logic, and then saving the data.  It could be done by creating a stored procedure or some other database-side logic to ensure valid data and then you only interact with the database once.  Etc.  Either way, it's up to you to define and validate the business rules set forth in your system.

Comment: thanks for reply,im using a trigger to validate province belong to selected country or manipulated.actually i want to know whats the best solution?do it in database-side or keep the all validation in php?which one impact performance less? or maybe there is laravelish way to this approach?

Comment: The business logic validation should surely happen within your application code. Thinking about performance impact of such a trivial task is definitely a case for premature optimization and the bikeshed effect. The "laravelish" approach to this is to simply check if the relation exists between the `Question` and the `Answer` models. If you need more details, please consider updating your question with code samples of what you've done so far, what models do you have and what your controller code looks like.

Comment: @ArashMoosapour: I'm not entirely familiar with the patterns and practices of Laravel itself, but in general I would favor putting logic like this in the application code.  Now, the boundary between "application" and "data store" can (and often does) shift significantly, depending on the overall architecture of the system.  In some systems "data store" scaffolding pushes into the DAL of the application, while in other systems "application logic" pushes into the RDBMS.  Every system is different and does things for different reasons.

Answer (score 2):

In your controller, you can do something like this:

```
# Get the ids of the answers that are valid for that question
$validAnswerIds = $Question->answers->pluck('id')->toArray();

# Validate that the answer given is in there
$rules = ['answer' => Rule::in( $validAnswerIds ) ];
$request->validate( $rules );
```

Answer (score 2):

As [David has already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47263879/65732), you gonna need to validate your business logic.

The most "laravelish" way, as [you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263762/validate-exposed-primary-keys-in-a-form-are-intact#comment81479387_47263879), is to perform validations within your request classes and develop extra validator extensions if needed. Littering your controllers with validation logic, as [Erin has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47264970/65732), is not a good practice at all; it works though.

I assume you're having two separate models: `Question` and `Answer`. Also, a full 1-N relationship set between them in a way that a question can have many answers and each answer belongs to a question:

```php
class Question extends Model
{
    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }
}

class Answer extends Model
{
    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }
}
```

Let's say you also have a `SurveyController`:

```php
class SurveyController extends Controller
{
    public function store(CreateSurveyRequest $request)
    {
        // Request is validated by now and you can be sure that the 
        // answer belongs to the question. Go on and create/store 
        // the Survey entity.
    }
}
```

And the request class which does the actual data validation:

```php
class CreateSurveyRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        // Assuming the request contains `answer_id` and `question_id` fields:

        return [
            'answer_id' => 'exists:answers,id,question_id,' . request('question_id'),
            // e.g. 
            // 8 => 'exists:answers,id,question_id,10'
            // Which loosly translates to "answer ID 8 should belong to question ID 10"
        ];
    }
}
```

Such `exists` rule definition makes sure that the answer record has a foreign key on the `questions` table and thus it's a valid answer to the question.

The point is that Laravel's `exists` rule [supports additional conditions](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1140). Interesting, the guy filing the proposal was feeling the exact same need you're having here.

Comment: very detailed answer ,thank you. I've managed to solve my problem with [Custom Rule Objects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules). i think this way my code is much cleaner and reusable.by the way i didn't know Laravel's exists rule supports additional conditions. that's interesting @sepehr

Comment: Sure thing, @ArashMoosapour. Yeah, using rule classes or validator extensions are primary methods of implementing custom validations. Your case can be good candidate for a `belongs` cutom rule. However, I personally prefer to stick to generic core functionality and avoid added complexity whenever   possible.